# Can God forgive anyone's sin?

Tags: karma, sin

Can God forgive anyone's sin. Or no matter what a person has to bear the fruits of his karma ?

Comment: This questions the God's omnipotence, so God can do anything. But what he do  and how he do, we don't know.

Comment: God can forgive but not the nature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sarva-dharmān parityajya
mām ekaṁ śaraṇaṁ vraja
ahaṁ tvāṁ sarva-pāpebhyo
mokṣayiṣyāmi mā śucaḥ
(Bg. 18.66)

Krishna Says in Gita
Abandon all varieties of religion and just surrender unto Me. I shall deliver you from all sinful reactions. Do not fear.

God will not only forgive but he will wipe out all your karmic records. Only condition is that you have to surrender unconditionally.